WoL across subnets
I want to turn on my Windows PC from a Docker container with WoL. The PC is IP 10.0.0.10, the server is 10.0.0.2 and the Docker container on that server is on a different subnet and has the IP 10.0.10.4 (I created a macvlan network and assigned it to that container - different network port with vlan10).
My UniFi router (UDM SE) blocks inter-vlan routing and I’ve created firewall exceptions to allow communications from 10.0.10.4 to 10.0.0.10 and the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet to the 10.0.10.0/24 subnet (vlan10).
The only way I found that allows WoL through different subnets was to force the broadcast address to the PC's IP address, 10.0.0.10. This works when I test it. However, when I wake up the next day and try to turn the PC on with WoL, there’s no response. I am completely lost with this and can’t find out the reason it behaves like that.

I have an UDM-Pro-Max  (which is similar to the SE) and have it configured for multiple VLANs but inter-vlan routing isn’t blocked by default until firewall rules are created. So have you considered making a specific rule to allow the traffic?

I don't quite get what you mean by "The only way I found that allows WoL through different subnets was to force the broadcast address to the PC's IP address, 10.0.0.10.". Can you say more? Exactly which kind of broadcast address are you talking about, and how are you forcing it to the PC's IP address?

https://superuser.com/a/1862243/816523

This question is similar to: Wake on Lan not working even though WireShark captures it. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

On your router that routes between the two subnets in question, you probably need to enter a permanent/static ARP table entry for the target machine.
Many machines with more old-school, rudimentary WOL support don't respond to ARP while asleep, so after about 2 minutes of sleeping, the router has timed out the ARP table entry for that machine and deleted the entry from the table. So it's forgotten the ARP mapping from the sleeping machine's IP address (10.0.0.10) to its MAC address. So when the WOL magic packet reaches the router from the other subnet, and the router wants to forward it onto the target subnet's LAN, the router doesn't know how to address it at the Ethernet layer, and it can't get the answer via ARP because the sleeping machine isn't responding to ARP. So to prevent this, you need to ensure that the router always has an ARP table entry for the target machine.
Many consumer routers don't have a way to do this in the factory firmware. Some consumer routers are even so dumb as to have a DHCP lease reservation feature ("always assign this IP address to this client MAC address"), but still not tie it to their ARP table. So even though your router's DHCP server feature knows this IP to MAC address mapping, its ARP table might not know it. If your router doesn't have a way to set a permanent static ARP table entry, you might want to see if you can run OpenWrt or some other open source router firmware distro on it in order to get that ability.

Spiff's solution is probably the simplest, some other options would be an iptables rule to re-write a normal IP address (an unused one) to the broadcast address so that you can trigger a L3 broadcast from a different subnet, or you may be able to proxy arp for the host that is offline from another machine to keep the arp cache warm (again a static ARP entry is the best/simplest solution).

Thanks for the explanation. It's now clear to me the reason I can't wake up the PC the next day. Unfortunately the UDM SE doesn't provide a method of altering the ARP tables like some older UniFi devices. My solution right now is using a docker container in the main network with a WoL client and a web API that I can call from the IoT network.

@mignz Glad to hear you got it resolved. BTW, one person was sure all modern PC Ethernet interfaces have WoL ARP proxy support built in. Can you check your advanced driver properties for your Windows PC's Ethernet port and see if there's anything like that, that maybe got disabled somehow? It would also be great if you could document exactly what Ethernet controller hardware you have in your Windows PC, and what driver version, so we can check whether that hardware/driver combination does or does not have WoL ARP proxy.

It's a Marvell AQtion AQC113CS 10Gbit adapter. The only setting I see is ARP Offload, which is enabled. I still think this is the solution but not possible on the UDM SE.

@mignz ARP Offload is supposed to solve this problem. I wonder why it's not working?

The answer Zac67 linked has an interesting point about directed broadcasts. I did some experimentation and as long as I enable directed broadcasts on the docker interface:
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/docker0/bc_forwarding 

And the main flag:
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/bc_forwarding 

Assuming that the primary subnet is a /24, I can send a directed broadcast wakeonlan packet from the docker container:
wakeonlan -i 10.0.0.255 11:22:33:44:55:66

As this is a broadcast, it is not necessary to mess with ARP and the packet is delivered to all hosts on the LAN.
Edit: I have confirmed only the Docker (inbound) interface and "all" need to be set the there is no need to enable the outbound interface.

Just to make it clear, directed broadcasts need to be enabled on the last hop router (the one on the target LAN), which in OP's case is the UniFi router. The relevant setting seems to be called "Forward Net Directed Broadcasts".

In my testing my docker containers were running on a different subnet, but they were being NATed by the docker host machine onto the LAN (I don't have an external router). I agree the final hop router will need to enable directed broadcasts, however I am unsure if the Docker host will need these settings too since it is aware of of the final subnet "the server is 10.0.0.2 and the Docker container on that server"

From what I understand the docker container in OP's situation is directly connected to a different VLAN, so the host is not actually doing any routing. But I may have gotten it wrong.

My concern is where/if the Linux kernel determines that the packet is a directed broadcast - since it knows that the 10.0.0.0/24 network exists it may determine that the outbound packet is a directed broadcast even though it is not doing the routing (I don't know, just speculating you might need the settings anyway).

The only router which know it's a directed broadcast is the one connected to the destination (V)LAN. In OP's case, neither the client nor the server (which are on 10.0.0.0/24) know anything about 10.0.10.255, other than it's in a different network, and should be send to the router (they don't know anything about 10.0.10.0/24). When it reaches the final (which is here also the last) router, the router knows that 10.0.10.255 is a broadcast because it's connected to 10.0.10.0/24, and it can decide to broadcast the packet or not based on its own config.

Traffic to 10.0.10.0/24 is not "really" sent to the server hosting the container. It is sent on a VLAN which is directly connected to the container, so the host OS doesn't route anything (it doesn't really know about 10.0.10.0/24, it knows that VLAN 10 goes to the container). -- At least that's what I understood from OP's description.

Also, I can't do this on a Synology server. Or at least not permanently so I'm avoiding this solution.
